# Infinite 'while' loop

Tags: ruby

Basically it is Rails code, but here is pure Ruby problem.
For you to know - @test.source is some String, which can contain `' '` (spaces). The aim is to delete all unnecessary spaces, which go after first. For example,`%some word' '' '` should leave `%some word' '`, `%another word' '' '' '` should leave `%another word' '` and so on.

```
for i in 0...@test.source.length
      if @test.source[i] == ' '
          i=i+1
          while @test.source[i] == ' '
              @test.source[0...i].chop
          end
      else
          i+=1
      end
  end
```

For some reason this loop (obviosly 'while') is infinite. Why?

Comment: usually thats done with a regex, for example: `@test.source.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')`

Comment: regular expressions seems to be powerfull tool

Comment: but that also deletes all newlines, how to fix that?

Comment: read up on regular expressions! you would use `/\ /` (an escaped space) to match a space. `\s` matches any whitespace character (including new lines) and `+` means 1 or more

Comment: `source.gsub(/[^\S+\n]/, ' ')` That should replace all whitespaces with one except the newline whitespaces, am i right?

Comment: Close. `/[^\S\n]+/` is what you want, meaning "match one or more characters that aren't: not whitespace or new line". `[]` in regexes makes a whitelist of chars, and `[^]` makes a blacklist. But they still represent one char in the match, so the `+` is applied to the char set

Comment: Thank you very much, now I study this topic and make experiments at [rubular](http://rubular.com/), regexp helps to avoid a lot of unnecessary typing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't incrementing `i` within the while loop, so the while loop will always compare the specified character with `' '` without ever moving on.

Change it to this:

```
      <% while @test.source[i] == ' ' %>
          <% @test.source[0...i].chop %>
          <% i=i+1 %>
      <% end %>
```

...but even then, there are still problems with your code. It's an exercise for the reader to see the remaining issues. :)

Comment: Thanks. That works. But i don't get, as I use chop, shouldn't @test.source[i] at new loop be that previosly was @test.source[i-1]?

Comment: [`String#chop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chop) doesn't modify the original string. If you wanted that, you'll need to use [`String#chop!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chop-21). But, even then, as Dai says, there are better (more idiomatic) ways to accomplish what you want.